# Got error during import file in tally prime

Tags: xml, tally

I have tried to import the invoice voucher XLSX file in tally prime. I have followed the below steps

1. converted xlsx to xml
2. imported file to tally prime.

I have got an error in the second step.

[image: error]

xml code for voucher import in tally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ENVELOPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <HEADER>
  <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
 </HEADER>
 
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
           <REQUESTDESC>
    <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
     <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>xyz pvt ltd</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
   </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <VOUCHER VCHTYPE="Sales" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Invoice Voucher View">
                        <DATE>20211130</DATE>
                        <REFERENCEDATE>20211130</REFERENCEDATE>
                        <STATENAME>Odisha</STATENAME>
                        <COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>India</COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>
                        <PLACEOFSUPPLY>Odisha</PLACEOFSUPPLY>
                        <PARTYNAME>Odisha</PARTYNAME>
                        <PARTYLEDGERNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                        <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                        <REFERENCE>OD123510562192973000</REFERENCE>
                        <PARTYMAILINGNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</PARTYMAILINGNAME>
                        <CONSIGNEEGSTIN>08AEHPB4710R2ZA</CONSIGNEEGSTIN>
                        <CONSIGNEEMAILINGNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</CONSIGNEEMAILINGNAME>
                        <CONSIGNEESTATENAME>Odisha</CONSIGNEESTATENAME>
                        <VOUCHERNUMBER>FAFLPR22000123456</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                        <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                        <PERSISTEDVIEW>Invoice Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
                        <BASICBUYERNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</BASICBUYERNAME>
                        <BASICFINALDESTINATION>Odisha</BASICFINALDESTINATION>
                        <CONSIGNEECOUNTRYNAME>India</CONSIGNEECOUNTRYNAME>
                        <VCHENTRYMODE>Item Invoice</VCHENTRYMODE>
                        <ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                            <BASICUSERDESCRIPTION.LIST>
                                <BASICUSERDESCRIPTION>Fit Men White Trousers</BASICUSERDESCRIPTION>
                            </BASICUSERDESCRIPTION.LIST>
                            <STOCKITEMNAME>MT230_12_WHITE_38</STOCKITEMNAME>
                            <RATE>449.0</RATE>
                            <AMOUNT>449.0</AMOUNT>
                            <ACTUALQTY>5.0</ACTUALQTY>
                            <BILLEDQTY>5.0</BILLEDQTY>
                            <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                                <LEDGERNAME>Interstate Sales 5%</LEDGERNAME>
                            </ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                        </ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                    </VOUCHER>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I am new to tally. Not suffient knowlegde of tally. Please help to solve error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the voucher manually in Tally and **Export to XML** then you will know what are required fields

Your Voucher Doesn't contain all **required** fields

there will be other **<LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>** with Customer ledger name (xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd) with amount

Inside **ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST** there is no Amount at all

If you add amount in LEDGERENTRIES + ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS It should be zero (In Invoice Voucher View)